# How to autostart `ypbind` on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, init.d, nis

It seems I need to use `sysv-rc-conf` to manage service startup/shutdown, but no scripts were added to `/etc/init.d/` when I installed NIS. I would expect to either have `/etc/init.d/nis` or `/etc/init.d/ypbind`.

I installed NIS via `apt-get` as so:

```
sudo apt-get install nis
```

**How do I configure `ypbind` to start automatically when Ubuntu 14.04 boots?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `/var/log/upstart/ypbind.log` file, I saw `ypbind` was failing to bind to the server at boot and just quitting. There was actually no problem with auto-starting `ypbind`.

I determined this was due to DNS not being available at early boot, so I added a couple entries to my `/etc/hosts` file for the two NIS servers and voila!

Cheers!
--ap